# Calculating the Hamming distance

Tags: strings, lua

That's an easy one. I just want to calculate the Hamming distance between two strings.

```
function hamming(str1,str2)
  local distance = 0

  -- cannot calculate Hamming distance if strings have different sizes
  if #str1 ~= #str2 then return false end

  for i = 1, #str1 do
    if str1:sub(i,i) ~= str2:sub(i,i) then
      distance = distance + 1 
    end
  end

  return distance
end
```

Maybe the for-loop isn't the most efficient one. I'm not sure. Any improvements?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing inefficient about your loop.  You are simply counting from `1` to `#str1`.  Both bounds are known in advance.  This is as good as it gets with loops in Lua.

The only improvement I could think of was using `string.byte` instead of `string.sub`, avoiding the interning of 1-character substrings.  Even then, the difference is negligible, because the overhead of calling a C function (`sub` or `byte`) from the interpreter takes most of the CPU time.

Unless you run it under LuaJIT that is.  Under LuaJIT, `byte` will be inlined into the body of the loop (where is consists only of a bounds check + array access) and the string interning (which requires an allocation + hash table lookup) dominates the CPU time.